# How I can fix the "value error" for my CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Firstly, my level in English is bad, so sorry for that.

So when I start the training of my CNN, it return this error :

ValueError: `validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy arrays, found following types in the input: [<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, .... ]

I'm beginner at CNN. I don't know where is the error, so I put my entire code here (written by sentdex YouTube channel) :

## create my training data

```
import numpy as np

import os
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
import pickle
import random

DATADIR = "C:/content/datasets/Cats and dogs 2"

CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]
IMG_SIZE = 100
training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:  # do dogs and cats

        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to dogs and cats
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)  # get the classification  (0 or a 1). 0=dog 1=cat

        for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):  # iterate over each image per dogs and cats
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))  # convert to array
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))  # resize to normalize data size
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])  # add this to our training_data
            except Exception as e:  # in the interest in keeping the output clean...
                pass
            #except OSError as e:
            #    print("OSErrroBad img most likely", e, os.path.join(path,img))
            #except Exception as e:
            #    print("general exception", e, os.path.join(path,img))

create_training_data()
print(training_data)
random.shuffle(training_data)

X = []
y = []

for features,label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
print(y)

pickle_out = open("X.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

pickle_out = open("y.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

## Build and train the neural network

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

import pickle

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors

model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.1)
```

Perhaps the "reshape at the array X" is strange, pycharm tell me that the two last arguments are unexpected.

Please tell me if you see improvement going for my code,

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ValueError: validation_split is only supported for Tensors or NumPy
> arrays, found following types in the input: [<class 'int'>, <class
> 'int'>, <class 'int'>, .... ]

```
for features,label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
```

Combine your code with the error, y is a list in your code, try to convert it to numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! But I already try to do that and I have the error : samples are not the same, cardinality problem